# Rails simply not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm really up-to-hear with frustration to the point where I don't think I'll ever try to use rails again.  This is the second time I've tried to use it and I honestly can't even get started.

Anyway now that I've blown off that steam, here is a description of what's happening and where I'm stuck.

I have a site `example.com`.  This site has a `.htaccess` that does a lot of redirection (it works off a single file in the document root that loads the appropriate controllers and what have you).  Using cpanel, I set up `blog.example.com`.  The document root for it is `example.com/blog`.  I decided I might as well try to use RoR for the blog and learn something new.

I got started with this guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html -- their rails version seems to be 3.1.3.  The one on my server is 3.0.9, but I don't think this should make a difference for such simple stuff.  I trudged through getting things set up to use MySQL.  I'm probably way off, but I at least wanted a page to print.

After installation, I created a symlink from the RoR `public` to the `blog` document root.  Visiting `blog.example.com` displays the RoR "smoke test" page.  Wonderful.

Clicking on "About your application’s environment" (links to `http://blog.example.com/rails/info/properties`) redirects to `example.com`.  This is a really bad sign.  I have no idea why it would redirect not just to its own document root, but to the document root of the main domain.  I thought it was because of the redirection going on in `example.com`'s `.htaccess`, so I removed said .htaccess.  No dice -- the same redirection happens.  I thought that it might be the browser cache too, but clearing the cache and even using a different browser still causes this redirection!  I have to conclude that `rails` itself is redirecting from `blog.example.com/rails/info/properties` to `example.com`, but that doesn't make any sense -- especially since I haven't touched anything on the RoR app end at all.

Anyway, I decide to continue on.  I create a controller with `rails generate controller home index`.  The files all seem to be in order.  I also updated `root :to` in `routes.rb` to `home#index`.

`rake routes` prints:

```
home_index GET /home/index(.:format) {:controller=>"home", :action=>"index"}
     root      /(.:format)           {:controller=>"home", :action=>"index"}
```

I remove `app/public/index.html` as instructed so the default route will show up.

With the `example.com/.htaccess`, visiting `/` simply gives a 404, and visiting `/first/index` (or `/first`, `/first/`, or `/first/index/`) all redirect to `example.com`.  Once again, I removed the `.htaccess` since it's probably causing the redirects.  I'm not sure whether it's the server or some other black magic, but removing the `.htaccess` *still* causes redirects to `example.com` even though it no longer works since it needs the `.htaccess` to rewrite appropriately on its own.  Using another browser seems to fix that, though.

However, I *still* get a 404 for visiting `/` or `/first/index` or any variant thereof.  `log/product.log` has lots of:

```
Started GET "/first/index/" for ?.?.?.? at 2012-03-14 15:40:59 -0400

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/first/index"):

Started GET "/" for ?.?.?.? at 2012-03-14 15:41:57 -0400

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/"):
```

...but `rake routes` shows that there are routes available for these.  `app/view/home/index.html.erb` exists and has `<h1>Home#index</h1>...`  What's weird is that the `log` does not always seem to record that error on every visit, so maybe the server or something is caching the response -- I don't know, but I do know that I get a 404 every time even though `rake` is even saying the routes exist (and inspecting `config/routes.rb` and `app/controllers/home_controller.rb` seems to indicate that they should exist too).

Apologies for the long summary, but this information may all be pertinent.  My question is twofold:

1) How do I get `blog.example.com` to ignore `example.com`'s `.htaccess` or otherwise ignore the redirects (assuming that it is the `.htaccess` causing them -- I'm not 100% sure that is the case but it seems likely).  For reference, the `.htaccess` is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RedirectMatch example/(.*)$ http://example.com/$1

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.html/$0/ [PT]
```

2) How do I get the RoR controllers to work period?  I've followed the instructions for setting up the routes to the letter -- nothing on my end looks wrong, but I'm still getting 404s so I'm really not sure what to do.

Comment: i'm confused, are you trying to deploy your application or simply get one running locally to develop?  I'm not sure I'd try the first before the second.

Comment: @miked I guess both at the same time?

Comment: have you tried simply serving with the built in WEBrick server?

Comment: @miked I don't know what those words mean :/

Comment: what is your front server (apache / nginx), what is your app server (webrick, thin, unicorn, passenger), and what is your setting to link them ? That seems to be a deployment issue. `htaccess` has nothing to do directly with rails. I recommend you to developp and debug your app locally and then to interest in deploying your app on prod...

Comment: @Artimuz front server is apache.  I have no idea what the app server is, the setting to link them, or how to find out.  I'm also trying to use instructions from my shared host to get rails going, but they appear to be horribly outdated too.  I know that at least rails is running.  I could develop locally in theory, but the server and my comp are different OSen.

Comment: You have to understand that RoR is... ruby, not statix content or php. So apache without the good mods can't serve a RoR app. Generally you have to run an app server (the `rails s`) and proxy requests for it with your front server (apache). You can use [Phusion Passenger](http://www.modrails.com/). But as @miked told you : first, give a rails a try _locally_, on your computer, because you don't seem to know the basics (like routing). Then do some google search on "_deploy rails app_".

Comment: @Artimuz well, I am running this on a shared host so I have absolutely no control over the proxy or the server unfortunately.  I don't see how getting it to work locally would help if deploying is another step (and the server technology could be different).  I think that'll be it for rails and I .. I'll just go about doing this in a way that doesn't require so many steps.  It's just a simple blog after all.

Comment: @tandu - that's unfortunate, IMO, you're really missing out on a fun framework, but you're attempting to develop in a paradigm that virtually nobody in this community develops in (because it's entirely unnecessary) and then asking for help on something without any firm foundation of the framework.  Effective help, through a forum of all places, is impossible if you don't want to follow the advice that seasoned developers are recommending.  It's really only as difficult as you want to make it. Best of luck to you.

Comment: @tandu One last advice: most shared hosts are not properly configured to serve rails, but just a single PHP/MySql app. If it is so easy to deploy, that is because your host provider has done the server config for you for this specific type of app. If your host support RoR, they _should_ have document how to get it running. You should rely on this doc. Most of your issues are not Rails issues, but server config issues. Serving a rails app is not just making a symlink to it, because unlike `.php` files, `.rb` files aren't served on the fly : ruby app server must be running in memory before.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've got rails installed (which it sounds like you have).  What happens with this?:

```
$>rails new myapplication
$>cd myapplication
$>rails s
```

then nav to: http://localhost:3000

Comment: I'm doing this on shared hosting rather than my own computer, so `localhost` is not going to work .. what is `rails s`?

Comment: well, there's part of your problem.  Rails is painfully simple to get up and running locally (on your own computer).  I'd recommend doing that before trying to configure it on a shared host.  It doesn't sound like you made it to step 4 on http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html as 'rails s' starts a local web server so you can see your app and develop against it.

Comment: but then how come I can see the "smoke test" landing page?

Comment: likely because it's a static page that your web server is serving up from the public directory (or whatever you have symlinked it to).  For an initial try at Rails, you could not really have a worse scenario - that is trying to run on a shared host in a subdomain. Please do yourself a favor and FIRST try it out locally to understand the Rails framework, then attempt on a deployment to a shared host.  There are too many variables at work here to effectively help you.

Comment: Well, I was able to get the root controller page to show up after all (I don't really know why..I didn't do anything), but the same URL to that page makes the redirect.